# Can not import modules in Haskell

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, haskell-stack

Hello i am trying to use Haskell with vscode and if i try to use a module inside another i get the following error:

```
Failed to load interface for **Client**
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

First Module:

```
module Main where 

import qualified Client as Cl

main ::IO ()
main = do
name<- getLine
sp
```

Second module:

```
    module Client 
    (sp)where

    sp::IO()
    sp=print "SecondModule"
```

After some reading i tried updating stack and installing the build tools at which point i get the following error:

```
   $ stack install gtk2hs-buildtools
    ←[0mprimitive-0.6.3.0: using precompiled package←[0m
    ←[0mCabal-2.0.1.1: using precompiled package←[0m
    ←[0mmtl-2.2.1: using precompiled package←[0m
    ←[0mrandom-1.1: using precompiled package←[0m
    ←[0mtext-1.2.2.2: using precompiled package←[0m
    ←[0mvector-0.12.0.1: using precompiled package←[0m
    ←[0mtf-random-0.5: configure←[0m
    ←[0mhashable-1.2.6.1: using precompiled package←[0m
    ←[0mhappy-1.19.9: download←[0m
    ←[0mtf-random-0.5: build←[0m
    ←[0mhashtables-1.2.2.1: download←[0m
    ←[0mhashtables-1.2.2.1: configure←[0m
    ←[0mhashtables-1.2.2.1: build←[0m
    ←[0mhappy-1.19.9: configure←[0m
    ←[0mtf-random-0.5: copy/register←[0m
    ←[0mQuickCheck-2.10.1: download←[0m
    ←[0mhappy-1.19.9: build←[0m
    ←[0mQuickCheck-2.10.1: configure←[0m
    ←[0mQuickCheck-2.10.1: build←[0m
    ←[0mhashtables-1.2.2.1: copy/register←[0m
    ←[0mQuickCheck-2.10.1: copy/register←[0m
    ←[0malex-3.2.3: download←[0m
    ←[0malex-3.2.3: configure←[0m
    ←[0malex-3.2.3: build←[0m
    ←[0mhappy-1.19.9: copy/register←[0m
    ←[0malex-3.2.3: copy/register←[0m
    ←[0mgtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.3.1: download←[0m
    ←[0mgtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.3.1: configure←[0m
    ←[0mgtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.3.1: build←[0m
    ←[0mgtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.3.1: copy/register←[0m
    Completed 13 action(s).
    removeDirectoryRecursive:removeContentsRecursive:removePathRecursive:removeContentsRecursive:removePathRecursive:removeContentsRecursive:removePathRecursive:removeContentsRecursive:removePathRecursive:removeContentsRecursive:removePathRecursive:removeContentsRecursive:removePathRecursive:DeleteFile "C:\\Users\\aita\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\stack7744\\gtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.3.1\\.stack-work\\dist\\5c8418a7\\build\\gtk2hsC2hs\\gtk2hsC2hs.exe": permission denied (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)
```

I was careful not to have any other process use this folder but i don't get why the error.

Here is my **stack.yaml** file:

```
# This file was automatically generated by 'stack init'
#
# Some commonly used options have been documented as comments in this file.
# For advanced use and comprehensive documentation of the format, please see:
# https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/

# Resolver to choose a 'specific' stackage snapshot or a compiler version.
# A snapshot resolver dictates the compiler version and the set of packages
# to be used for project dependencies. For example:
#
# resolver: lts-3.5
# resolver: nightly-2015-09-21
# resolver: ghc-7.10.2
# resolver: ghcjs-0.1.0_ghc-7.10.2
# resolver:
#  name: custom-snapshot
#  location: "./custom-snapshot.yaml"
resolver: lts-10.7

# User packages to be built.
# Various formats can be used as shown in the example below.
#
# packages:
# - some-directory
# - https://example.com/foo/bar/baz-0.0.2.tar.gz
# - location:
#    git: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack.git
#    commit: e7b331f14bcffb8367cd58fbfc8b40ec7642100a
# - location: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/commit/e7b331f14bcffb8367cd58fbfc8b40ec7642100a
#   extra-dep: true
#  subdirs:
#  - auto-update
#  - wai
#
# A package marked 'extra-dep: true' will only be built if demanded by a
# non-dependency (i.e. a user package), and its test suites and benchmarks
# will not be run. This is useful for tweaking upstream packages.
packages:
- .
# Dependency packages to be pulled from upstream that are not in the resolver
# (e.g., acme-missiles-0.3)
# extra-deps: []

# Override default flag values for local packages and extra-deps
# flags: {}

# Extra package databases containing global packages
# extra-package-dbs: []

# Control whether we use the GHC we find on the path
# system-ghc: true
#
# Require a specific version of stack, using version ranges
# require-stack-version: -any # Default
# require-stack-version: ">=1.6"
#
# Override the architecture used by stack, especially useful on Windows
# arch: i386
# arch: x86_64
#
# Extra directories used by stack for building
# extra-include-dirs: [/path/to/dir]
# extra-lib-dirs: [/path/to/dir]
#
# Allow a newer minor version of GHC than the snapshot specifies
# compiler-check: newer-minor
Main
Client
```

**Cabal File.**

```
name:                Hworld
version:             0.1.0.0
-- synopsis:
-- description:
homepage:            https://github.com/githubuser/Hworld#readme
license:             BSD3
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Author name here
maintainer:          example@example.com
copyright:           2018 Author name here
category:            Web
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10
extra-source-files:  README.md

executable Hworld
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
```

Comment: Are you using GTK in your project? (If not, you don't actually need `gtk2hs-buildtools`; either way, as far as I can see your issue isn't related to that.)

Answer (score 10):

**First, `stack install` is a bit of a misnomer**. Unlike `npm install` or `bower install`, it doesn't download anything or "add" anything to your project. Under `stack`, all packages are (potentially, logically) downloaded and installed all the time. `stack` will build a package on first use, but there is no need to explicitly ask `stack` to download it.

What `stack install` actually does, it builds the package and, if the package contains any executables, it puts them in a special place on the file system that is on your `PATH`, so that now you can run those executables. Seeing how you can always run executables with `stack exec package` without installing them, using `stack install` is generally discouraged unless you're really sure it's necessary.

**To add a package to your project**, you need to include it in your `.cabal` file in `build-depends` section or in your `package.yaml` file in the `dependencies` section (whichever one you're using). [Here is an example of a `package.yaml`](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/package.yaml#L36), and [here's an example of a `.cabal` file](https://github.com/nick8325/quickcheck/blob/master/QuickCheck.cabal#L63).

But what you're trying to do, it seems, is to **reference *your own modules***, not external dependencies. For that, `stack install` is even further from the truth.

To reference your own modules, you need two things: (1) correct file system structure and (2) add them to `.cabal` or `package.yaml`.

**File system structure**: in Haskell (or, more precisely, in GHC), modules must be located in a place on the file system that matches their hierarchical name. For example, module `Main` would be located in `./Main.hs`, and module `Client` would be located in `./Client.hs`, or, say, module `Client.Internals` would be located in `./Client/Internals.hs`. A bit annoying, yes. But this is the way Haskell is.

**Cabal file**: all modules in a package/library must be listed in the `.cabal` file, either under `exposed-modules` or under `other-modules`. Just add them there, and the compiler will see them.

Comment: So you add all new created modules in the yaml file and that's it ? From there on it knows which go where depending on your module dependencies? I mean the .yaml file is like a global dump where all created modules must be found?

Comment: I added the stack.yaml file to the question.

Comment: Please see my update. I couldn't write it quite quickly enough.

Comment: Ok so i posted my cabal file .I have to create a section entitled "exposed-modules"?And if yes i just dump the names there?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Note that Fyodor Soikin points you to `package.yaml` (or, if you don't have one, the `.cabal` file), and not to `stack.yaml`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me out.I don't seem to have a package.yaml but i have a .cabal although without the "exposed-modules" or "other-modules"  section.

Comment: Just add those sections there.

Comment: Ok so i do not have those sections in the cabal file.But i added them and it is the same problem.I ran cabal build and i get the following:no location info>: warning: [-Wmissing-home-modules]
    These modules are needed for compilation but not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules: Test

Comment: Do you mean that you receive the same error message? Do you have the correct file structure? Can you show it? Can you show your `.cabal` file?

Comment: Thank you! `Client.Internals would be located in ./Client/Internals.hs` this is exactly what I was trying to fix!